# $(document).delegate not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

I am logged in to my site and now i want that if user is logged in then he/she will not redirect to index page

Here is jquery

```
$(document).delegate("#index", "pagebeforeshow", function() {
    $.post('functions/session_check.php', {
        }, function(data) {
            var status = $.trim(data);
            if(status=="logged in"){
                window.location.href='welcome.html';
            }
        })
});
```

and here is my php

```
<?php

include '../include/config.php';
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
if (isset($email)) {
    print_r('logged in');
}
?>
```

here  is html

```
<div data-role="page" class="jqm-demos jqm-home" id="index">
            <div data-role="header" class="jqm-header">
                <h1><img src="_assets/img/jquery-logo.png" alt="jQuery Mobile"></h1>
            </div>
            <div role="main" class="ui-content">
```

but the problem is: it is not going inside this code.

```
}, function(data) {
                var status = $.trim(data);
                if(status=="logged in"){
                    window.location.href='welcome.html';
                }
            })
```

Comment: and what's the problem?

Comment: you do not start the session by `session_start()` at the top of your php. is it in `config.php` ?

Comment: after $.post function(data) is not firing

Comment: `pagebeforeshow` is jquerymobile. Are you sure this is not related to jquerymobile?

Comment: session is started in include '../include/config.php';

Comment: yes pagebeforeshow  is jquery mobile event type. I also tried pageshow,

Comment: Why don't you just use `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: $(document).ready() is also not working.